# Cómo filtrar empresas por id de otra colección en Node JS y MongoDB?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, sql

Me encuentro elaborando un proyecto con Node JS y MongoDB como base de datos. Las colecciones que manejo son empresas y categorías:

Colección **Categorías**

```
var categoriaSchema = new Schema({
nombre: { type: String, required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario'] },
img: { type: String, required: false },
estado: { type: Boolean, default: true }});
```

Colección **Empresas**

```
var empresaSchema = new Schema({
nombre: { type: String, required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario'] },
img: { type: String, required: false },
estado: { type: Boolean, default: true },
categoria: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Categoria', required: [true, 'El id de la categoría es un campo obligatorio'] }});
```

A partir estas colecciones, necesito retornar las empresas por categoría definido por el usuario. Ya realicé la prueba del query en el Robo3T pero no estoy pudiendo conseguirlo en el Node JS.

Mi pregunta es, cómo implementar el query en el Node para que, cuando introduzca el **id de categoría** como un parametro de búsqueda en el Postman, me muestre solo las empresas que cuentan con ese id. Les dejo alguna capturas de pantallas.

[image: Colección de Categorías]

[image: Búsqueda de empresas según id de categoría]

[image: Código en Node JS]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta forma, creo que te servirá:

```
function buscarEmpresa(idCategory){ 
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { 
     Empresa.find({categoria: idCategory)}) 
         .then(resolve)
         .catch(resolve)
  })
}
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Saludos